# Sinatra fails to start to a very basic demo, template_cache is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

After gem install sinatra, I start a very basic demo code myapp.rb

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  'Hello world!'
end
```

after run "ruby myapp.rb", visit http://localhost:4567/ got failed

```
application error
NoMethodError at / 
undefined method `clear' for nil:NilClass

    file: base.rb location: call! line: 921 


BACKTRACE

 /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb in call! 

    def call!(env) # :nodoc:
      @env      = env
      @params   = IndifferentHash.new
      @request  = Request.new(env)
      @response = Response.new
      template_cache.clear if settings.reload_templates
```

here template_cache is nil, my sinatra version is 2.0.3 and gem version 2.3.0.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Looks like this could better go here: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues

Comment: This is working for me with `Sinatra (v2.0.1)` and `ruby 2.4.1p111`. Maybe you change version to see if there is some incompatibility.

Comment: Ok also `Sinatra (v2.0.3)` and `ruby 2.4.1`. But **problems** with `Sinatra (v2.0.3)` and `ruby 2.5.0`: `cannot load such file -- sinatra (LoadError)`